# Estudiando angular y ng new nombre_app no funciona. Que estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
alberto@linuxdell:~/Escritorio/angular$ 

    ng new --name=02spa --version=7.1.4

? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS

Error: **Schematic input does not validate against the Schema**: {"name":"02spa","version":"7.1.4","routing":false,"style":"css"}
Errors:

  Data path ".name" should match format "html-selector".
```

Tambien probe con el comando:

```
ng new nombre_app
```

y da el mismo error.

---

Estas son las versiones que tengo:

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 10.14.2
OS: linux x64
Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.11.4
@angular-devkit/core         7.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.1.4
@schematics/angular          7.1.4
@schematics/update           0.11.4
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.6
```

gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Esto es una respuesta bastante corta. No uses un nombre que comience con un número para tu proyecto.

Comment: por que razón?...

Comment: El mismo error te lo dice: should match format(debe coincidir con el formato)

Comment: Solo cambia el nombre y va funcionar sin ningún problema

Comment: eso no me corresponde a mi comprobarlo @Victor pues no soy el autor de la pub. si te pregunté es para que tu aporte quede mas completo no solo indicando la solución; sino el origen del problema

Answer (score 3):

Estas utilizando nombre_app. Debes quitar el guion bajo, carácter que no esta permitido usa un nombre de solo caracteres alfabéticos o alfanuméricos y el problema estará solucionado

Comment: ¿Y sabes por qué no está soportado?

Comment: sinceramente no averigue, pero estaba haciendo unas pruebas en un comienzo utilizando el guion bajo (_) siguiendo un video antiguo y me hizo perder buenas horas averiguando el porque del error. Por lo que me acorde que en algunas aplicaciones el guion bajo no es valido, lo elimine y listo me permitio crear el proyecto